# Oracle DB 12c: sqlplus as sysdba causes ORA-01017

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Good day. If i do `sqlplus user/oracle@db` i have successfull connection with db.

If i do `sqlplus user/oracle@db as sysdba` i  have error ORA-01017.

But at the server this command executes successfully.

My tnsnames.ora:

```
db =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.100.175)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Also i can't do `sqlplus /@db as sysdba`. And after `sqlplus user@db as sysdba` i enter a password and have this error too. At the server this executes without errors. What is the problem?

Oracle VirtualBox with Win2008, Oracle 12c

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as sysdba` only if permission has been granted. Run

```
GRANT SYSDBA TO user;
```

in order to permit that.

`sqlplus /@db as sysdba` is not possible from a remote machine - this would open the database to entire world where everybody could connect with SYSDBA privileges without any password!

`sqlplus /@db as sysdba` is allowed only from local machine because there you are already authenticated (typically) as OS-User "oracle".

Comment: It's good and acceptable solution, thank you, but what to do with system user? Any fix for it exists?

Comment: What do you mean by `system user`?

Comment: User with name `system` that can be used for connect

Comment: If you mean Oracle user `SYSTEM`: An Oracle database has several internal accounts, `SYS` and `SYSTEM` are only two of them, there are some more. Leave them as they are.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitively possible to connect as SYSDBA from a remote machine, as you were doing: specifying a password, and not relying on the OS authentication mechanism (the operative system auth is not involved in the course of a remote authentication such this).

Only, you have to activate the password-file mechanism (that is disabled by default).

To do so, change the value of the parameter `remote_login_passwordfile` to either `shared` or `exclusive`. If it is `shared` it works for all databases run on that machine and can only contain the `SYS` user (while if is it `exclusive` it can contain any user and its scope is the target database).

**Important**: users are added to the password file only *after* the password-file was enabled and after they're granted the `SYSDBA` or `sysoper` privilege; i.e. pre-existing users won't be automatically added (!), you have to re-grant the `SYSDBA` or `SYSOPER` role to them.

Finally this view lets you peek at the logical content of the password file

```
select * from v$pwfile_users;
```

See [Creating and Maintaining a Password File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba007.htm#ADMIN11061) for more details.